# How can I speed up compile times when developing a Clang-based tool?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, precompiled-headers

I'm developing a Clang-based tool
(i.e., a [`ClangTool`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1ClangTool.html)),
but the time to recompile a source file is longer than I would like.
Specifically, for the small example program below, it takes about 7
seconds to compile this one file, and I've only `#included` a bare
minimum.  Once I start pulling in AST matchers, compile times climb to
20 seconds and more.  That's a lot of friction in the development cycle,
especially when learning a new API and hence fixing a large number of
syntax errors.

I found some slides called
[Building Clang/LLVM efficiently](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2015-04/slides/eurollvm-2015-build.pdf)
by Tilmann Scheller from a talk at EuroLLVM 2015 which show modest
improvement (less than a factor of 2) by changing which compiler is used
(specifically, compiling with a `clang` that has been compiled by
`gcc`).  I'm ignoring the linking improvements because linking is
tolerably fast in my case.

I tried using [GCC precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)
(PCH), but the results are mixed (details below).  While compilation with PCH takes
about half as long, generating the PCH in the first place takes more
than twice as long as ordinary compilation, produces a huge PCH file
(300-500 MB), and is somewhat of a hassle to use (I have to reorganize
`#includes` across my project, manage additional dependencies and files,
and carefully monitor the process to be sure the PCHs are being used).

Ideally, I would like to get compile times under one second.  After all,
my source file is only about 100 lines of code (LOC).  Now, the
preprocessor output has about 200K LOC, and the word `template` appears
in over 5000 of those lines, so I'm fully aware the compiler is doing
more than is immediately apparent.  But *my* code is not directly using
more than a tiny fraction of that.

As a point of comparison, when using the Python bindings, it takes about
0.05 seconds to *run* a script of comparably minimal complexity.  I
understand that the C++ bindings have richer functionality, but I'm not
using (yet?) anything beyond what the Python bindings have, yet suffer
orders of magnitude more delay due to using C++ instead of Python.  (No,
I don't want to switch to Python.)

Might there be, or could one reasonably create, an alternative set of
C++ bindings with capabilities similar to the Python interface but
vastly improved compilation time?  Or is there some other feasible way
to hit the goal of compilation in under a second?

I am aware of [`libclang`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html),
the C bindings for Clang.  But I don't want to write my tool in C any
more than I want to write it in Python (that is, not at all).  If there
were something like `libclang`, but with an idiomatic C++ interface,
that might solve the problem, but I don't see anything like that.

---

Some measurements of different variations, median-of-5 measurement with GCC-9.3:

| Options | No PCH | Gen PCH | Use PCH | PCH Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `g++` | 6.8 s | 14 s | 2.5 s | 342 MB |
| `g++ -O2` | 6.9 s | 14 s | 2.5 s | 345 MB |
| `g++ -g` | 8.6 s | 18 s | 4.1 s | 472 MB |
| `g++ -g -O2` | 8.9 s | 18 s | 4.3 s | 478 MB |

The `g++ -g` configuration is the one I care most about.

@HolyBlackCat suggested trying with `clang` as the compiler.  Here are the times for Clang+LLVM-14.0.0:

| Options | No PCH | Gen PCH | Use PCH | PCH Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `clang` | 5.6 s | 5.1 s | 2.3 s | 62 MB |
| `clang -O2` | 5.6 s | 5.2 s | 2.5 s | 62 MB |
| `clang -g` | 5.6 s | 5.2 s | 2.4 s | 62 MB |
| `clang -g -O2` | 5.7 s | 5.1 s | 2.6 s | 62 MB |

That's certainly an improvement over `g++`, and may well be what I do going forward, although it falls short of my sub-second goal.

For completeness, I also measured GCC-12.1, and found its to be about 2% worse than GCC-9.3 for all measured times.

My setup:

- Using binary distribution of `clang+llvm-14.0.0` downloaded from [github.com](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz).
- Compiling with GCC-9.3.0 on Linux Mint 20.1 for x86_64.
- Quad-core Intel i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50HGz.
- 8 GB RAM.
- Linux is running inside VMware Workstation 12.  (The VM is not the
  problem.  Many C++ projects compile very quickly in the VM, even
  faster than compilation under the Windows host.)
- Host is Windows 10 with 32 GB physical RAM.

Source file to compile:

```
// print-tu.cc
// Print contents of a Translation Unit.

// clang
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"               // clang::ASTConsumer
#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"                // clang::ASTContext
#include "clang/AST/DeclBase.h"                  // clang::Decl
#include "clang/AST/DeclGroup.h"                 // clang::DeclGroupRef
#include "clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h"          // clang::SourceLocation
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"     // clang::CompilerInstance
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h"   // clang::CompilerInvocation
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h"       // clang::FrontendAction, clang::ASTFrontendAction
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"   // clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"               // clang::tooling::ClangTool, clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory

// llvm
#include "llvm/ADT/StringRef.h"                  // llvm::StringRef
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"            // llvm::cl::extrahelp

// libc++
#include <iostream>                              // std::cout, etc.

// libc
#include <assert.h>                              // assert

using clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser;
using clang::tooling::ClangTool;
using clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory;

using clang::ASTConsumer;
using clang::ASTContext;
using clang::ASTFrontendAction;
using clang::CompilerInstance;
using clang::CompilerInvocation;
using clang::Decl;
using clang::DeclGroupRef;
using clang::DiagnosticConsumer;
using clang::FileManager;
using clang::FrontendAction;
using clang::PCHContainerOperations;
using clang::SourceLocation;
using clang::TargetOptions;

using llvm::StringRef;

using std::cout;


// Apply a custom category to all command-line options so that they are the
// only ones displayed.
static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");

// CommonOptionsParser declares HelpMessage with a description of the common
// command-line options related to the compilation database and input files.
// It's nice to have this help message in all tools.
static llvm::cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);

// A help message for this specific tool can be added afterwards.
static llvm::cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...\n");


// Implement ASTConsumer
class MyASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
public:      // data
  // The context for the TU, as established by 'Initialize'.
  ASTContext *m_astContext;

public:      // methods
  MyASTConsumer()
    : m_astContext(NULL)
  {}

  // This is called at the start of the TU.
  virtual void Initialize(ASTContext &ctx) override
  {
    m_astContext = &ctx;
  }

  // This is called at the end of the TU.
  virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &ctx) override
  {
    cout << "in HandleTranslationUnit\n";
    assert(m_astContext == &ctx);
  }

  virtual bool HandleTopLevelDecl(DeclGroupRef declGroup) override
  {
    cout << "in HandleTopLevelDecl\n";
    assert(m_astContext);

    for (Decl const *decl : declGroup) {
      SourceLocation loc = decl->getLocation();
      cout << "  decl at "
           << loc.printToString(m_astContext->getSourceManager()) << '\n';
      cout << "    kind name: " << decl->getDeclKindName() << '\n';
    }

    return true;
  }
};


// Implement the FrontendAction interface.
//
// Inheriting from ASTFrontendAction provides definitions for
// 'ExecuteAction' and 'usesPreprocessorOnly'.
class MyFrontendAction : public ASTFrontendAction {
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
    CompilerInstance &ci,
    StringRef inFile) override
  {
    cout << "in CreateASTConsumer\n";

    TargetOptions const &targetOptions = ci.getTargetOpts();
    cout << "  target options triple: " << targetOptions.Triple << '\n';

    cout << "  inFile: " << inFile.str() << '\n';

    return std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer>(new MyASTConsumer());
  }
};


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  if (!ExpectedParser) {
    // Fail gracefully for unsupported options.
    llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
    return 2;
  }
  CommonOptionsParser& OptionsParser = ExpectedParser.get();
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  // Arrange to run 'MyFrontendAction' on each TU.
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<MyFrontendAction>().get());
}


// EOF
```

Compilation command (without `-g` or `-O2`):

```
g++ -c -o print-tu.o print-tu.cc $(llvm-config --cxxflags)
```

Comment: I would try compiling with Clang, with and without PCH. Long PCH generation times shouldn't be a concern, as long as the PCHed headers don't change often.

Comment: 20 seconds is 'a lot of friction'? Really? Do you correct your source files one character at a time? I've endured systems not too long ago where compile * build time was a couple of dozen *minutes,* and in the old days the turnaround time between compiler runs was 24 *hours.* You need to get more efficient at what you do.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good suggestion to measure `clang`.  I should have done that to begin with.  Edited question.

Comment: Do you include link time in your measurements? If yes, try Clang with LLD (pass `-fuse-ld=lld-14` or `-fuse-ld=lld` when linking).

Comment: @user207421 My question is about the time to compile *one* file.  At scale (1M+ LOC), 20 seconds per file is indeed costly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The measurements do not include link times.  For my present usage, linking only takes about a second, and is amortized over all the source files.  Plus I haven't even been using dynamic linking yet.  But I'll keep your suggestion in mind if/when that becomes an issue.  :)

Comment: Use generated dependencies for headers and only rebuild what is changed. ccache can help when you have to *make clean* or changed something not affecting the current architecture. Beyond that there isn't much that can be done. Maybe build with -Os or -O1 so the optimizer doesn't try so hard.